# clip to content within page when using pgfpages

Tags: beamer, pgfpages

When creating handouts with `pgfpages` the included content does not adhere to the page boarder.

The slide in the following example only shows the top part of an image

[image]

However the whole image is included in the handout:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-10x16}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this one can set a `corner width` for the included pages. Even if the corner width is 0, this still ensures that only the content within the page is shown:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{6 on 1}
{
    \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperwidth} % landscaped by default
    \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperheight}
    \def\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
    \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
    {%
        logical pages=6,%
        physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
        physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth,%
    }
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
    {%
        border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
        resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
        resized height=.25\pgfphysicalheight,%
        center=\pgfpoint{.29\pgfphysicalwidth}{.8333\pgfphysicalheight},
        %
        corner width=0pt
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
    {%
        border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
        resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
        resized height=.25\pgfphysicalheight,%
        center=\pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth}{.8333\pgfphysicalheight},%
        corner width=0pt
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}
    {%
        border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
        resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
        resized height=.25\pgfphysicalheight,%
        center=\pgfpoint{.29\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight},%
        corner width=0pt
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}
    {%
        border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
        resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
        resized height=.25\pgfphysicalheight,%
        center=\pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight},%
        corner width=0pt
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{5}
    {%
        border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
        resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
        resized height=.25\pgfphysicalheight,%
        center=\pgfpoint{.29\pgfphysicalwidth}{.1667\pgfphysicalheight},%
        corner width=0pt
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{6}
    {%
        border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
        resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
        resized height=.25\pgfphysicalheight,%
        center=\pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth}{.1667\pgfphysicalheight},%
        corner width=0pt
    }%   
}
\pgfpagesuselayout{6 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-10x16}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]